# How to use memcached on Win32?

Tags: java, memcached

I am using Win32 [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) from http://labs.northscale.com/memcached-packages/
And there is a DLL file within the package.

Now I am trying to write my Java project to use memcached. Somebody suggested 
Java -> JNI -> Custom DLL -> standard DLL call -> 3rd Party DLL in order to use the API.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run [Memcached](http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32/) as a separate program, possibly as a service, and you connect to it through TCP/IP. That's how it works on other platforms too.

You *don not* load Memcached as a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Java Memcached clients, such as http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/ and https://github.com/gwhalin/Memcached-Java-Client/wiki Using those is probably easier than re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: Yes, I can use those clients. But before using client, I have to start the memcached on win32, and make it bind with port 11211, am I right? No document specify that clearl. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to start the memcached server separately (it can even be on a different machine, that's why it's usually handled separately from the application that needs the caching).